# How can I expand a collapsed menu on the Wayback Machine?

Tags: html

I am trying to extract historical data on vehicle features using the Wayback Machine. On https://web.archive.org/web/20210305005624/https://www.toyota.com/mirai/features/mileage_estimates/3002/3003, you need to expand submenues to see all of the features. This is not working for me. Does anyone know how to fix this?

When I look at the HTML code, I can see the information, it just isn't clear which model the information applies to.

Thank you.